# find the farest white pixel from the top or the nearest from the bottom and get pixel co-ordinates

Tags: python, image, numpy, indexing, pixel

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0  I tried changing the target to a tuple, list etc. I cannot find what's the issue. img_bottom is a  **binary image**

```
def find_farest_white(img, target):
    nonzero = np.argwhere(img>0)
    distances = np.sqrt((nonzero[:,1] - TARGET[0]) ** 2 + (nonzero[:,0] - TARGET[1]) ** 2)
    farest_index = np.argmax(distances)
    return nonzero[farest_index]

TARGET=(0,0)

EDGEB=[]
#for i in range(img_bottom.shape[0]):
for j in range(0,img_bottom.shape[1]):
    for i in range(0,img_bottom.shape[0]):
        IMG=img_bottom[i,j]
        edge=find_farest_white(IMG,TARGET)
        EDGEB.append(edge)
        i+=1
    j+=1
```

But I'm getting this error

```
"
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-356-0118c2f70139> in <module>
      4     for i in range(0,img_bottom.shape[0]):
      5         IMG=img_bottom[i,j]
----> 6         edge=find_farest_white(IMG,TARGET)
      7         EDGEB.append(edge)
      8         i+=1

<ipython-input-353-ebd36711b415> in find_farest_white(img, target)
      1 def find_farest_white(img, target):
      2     nonzero = np.argwhere(img>0)
----> 3     distances = np.sqrt((nonzero[:,1] - TARGET[0]) ** 2 + (nonzero[:,0] - TARGET[1]) ** 2)
      4     farest_index = np.argmax(distances)
      5     return nonzero[farest_index]

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 0 "
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that `image` is a 2-dimensional array when you pass it in to `find_farest_white`. The following (copied directly from your code but with my own array `image`) works just fine:

```py
TARGET = (0,0)
image = np.eye(5)
def find_farest_white(img):
    nonzero = np.argwhere(img>0)
    distances = np.sqrt((nonzero[:,1] - TARGET[0]) ** 2 + (nonzero[:,0] - TARGET[1]) ** 2)
    farest_index = np.argmax(distances)
    return nonzero[farest_index]
find_farest_white(image)
```

```
>>> array([4, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. there is no problem with the function. Works fine for extreme values. In the for loop when iterating over each row and column i have errors.

Comment: @Starcode1619 I see. In that case, can you provide a sample of what `img_bottom` is? That will help see how the loop is working.

Comment: Can you see this lunk. this is img_bottom https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9fDf.png

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. How are you loading the image in? With imageio? opencv? What is the output of `type(img_bottom)`?

Comment: I used opencv. type of the image is numpy.ndarray

Comment: So in that case, why are you looping through the coordinates of the image? The function you wrote already handles that. Just call `find_farest_white(img_bottom, TARGET)` and you'll have the farthest pixel from the origin in that image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243199/discussion-between-elijah-cox-and-starcode1619).